# How to get array of values from array of dictionary?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *arrTemp = @[
                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Copper",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(50),
                       @"Style" : @"India Pale Ale (IPA)"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Jet Black",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(35),
                       @"Style" : @"Stout"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Copper",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(25),
                       @"Style" : @"English Brown Ale"},

                     @{@"Appearance" : @"Deep Gold",
                       @"Bitterness" : @(25),
                       @"Style" : @"Bock"}
                     ];
```

From the above structure, how can we get the array of "Appearance" values.
Please help.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I just tried with my project details with  same structure and separate class which I should not post it here

Comment: A simple for loop should do the trick. It's basic algorithm (and quite base to learn). It doesn't work with your code? What code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE) is your friend. See the paragraph *Getting Attribute Values Using Keys*

```
NSArray *appearances = [arrTemp valueForKey:@"Appearance"];
```

`valueForKey` called on an array of dictionaries returns an array of all values for the specific key.

Comment: I have tried this. but I am getting only one value
but we need array of values
like : Copper,Jet Black, Copper,Deep Gold

Comment: If you test that code with your sample, you exactly get `@[@"Copper", @"Jet Black", @"Copper", @"Deep Gold"]`, which is the expected result.